# How to know which image is clicked, then a transparent place hidden from view other images

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I need clicked any image. I add few pictures to illustrate the situation

**black borders** is layer boundaries [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSFyE.png]

if i use **z-index on the red rhombus i cannot press blue and brown rhombus**, because hidden from view by a layer of transparent red diamond
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjnCK.png]

If i use z-index on the blue rhombus i cannot press red and brown rhombus**, because hidden from view by a layer of transparent blue diamond [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCiXf.png]

If i use z-index on the brown rhombus i cannot press red and blue rhombus, because hidden from view by a layer of transparent brown diamond [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYjom.png]

Comment: What about using CSS transform and rotate your items. I think it will do the trick. But of course you may have some cross browser compatibility issue.
It works, just look at this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cbxqwae3/

Comment: Using square images and css transform to rotate them might do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a new suggestion, but its not perfectly done. It needs a little work from your side. But it should be clear what you have to do ;)

```
> http://jsfiddle.net/sbkhtvmo/2/
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try it with imagemap an make only one image of all squares.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

Comment: <area shape="poly"coords="50,0,75,25,50,50,25,25" ...../> will define a rotated rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Apply a custoom attribute to your images and trigger in javascript(jquery) with a .live or .on function which images was clicked.

```
HTML:
<img class="rhombus" x="first layer"/>

JQuery:
...

$(document).on("click", ".rhombus", function(e){
alert($(this).attr("x");
});
...
```

Comment: then you should explain your problem so that everyone can understand your problem

Comment: You example try it: `http://jsfiddle.net/sbkhtvmo/1/` press near flower here: http://postimg.org/image/ubwhpj3tp/ program alerts i clicked second layer, but i press realy first layer